# Frame shift 'for' with motion path

Tags: perl, curses

I have a human object here.
In `my @path` there is a feeling that the human is floating, but not the frame change.
If change the parameter `callback_args => [0,[@path]]`, to `callback_args => [0,0,0,1]`, there is frame shift but no levitation of the puppet.
What keeps the frame up to date is the last digit being ≠ of 0; which corresponds to the exchange speed.
Which doesn't make sense since in `my $up` and `$down` the last digit is ≠ of 0. And the positions 0,-.3,0; X, Y, Z; I just change y to go up and down.
How to keep levitation and the two frame of the puppet?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

my $s = Term::Animation->new();
$s->color(1);  # <-- uses the color2 type mask
my @human= (q{
 o
/#\
/ \
},
q{
\o>
 #
/ \
});
my $up = [0,-.3,0,.5];
my $down = [0,.3,0,.5];

my @path;

for(1..14){ push(@path, $up); }
for(1..14){ push(@path, $down)}
$s->new_entity(
        shape           => \@human,
        position        => [ 5, 5, 1],
        callback_args   => [0, [@path] ],
        color           => 'w',
        wrap            => 1,
);

halfdelay( 2 );
for(1..500) {
    $s->animate();
    my $in = lc( getch() );
    if($in eq 'q') { last; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to keep levitation and the two frame of the puppet?

You are using the same shape (frame of shape) for all animation frames. Can you try setting the shape frame explicitly like this:

```
my @up = (0,-.3,0);
my @down = (0,.3,0);
my @path;
my $frame = 0;
for(1..14){ push @path, [@up, $frame]; $frame = ($frame + 1) %2;}
for(1..14){ push @path, [@down, $frame]; $frame = ($frame +1) %2;}
```